# In REST Assured, how can I check if a field is present or not in the response?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

How can I make sure that my response, let's say it is in JSON, either **contains** or **does not contain** a specific field?

```
when()
    .get("/person/12345")
.then()
    .body("surname", isPresent()) // Doesn't work...
    .body("age", isNotPresent()); // ...But that's the idea.
```

I'm looking for a way to assert whether my JSON will contain or not the fields **age** and **surname**.

Answer (score 83):

You can use the Hamcrest matcher [*hasKey()*](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasKey%28K%29) (from `org.hamcrest.Matchers` class) on JSON strings as well.

```
when()
    .get("/person/12345")
.then()
    .body("$", hasKey("surname"))
    .body("$", not(hasKey("age")));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, why not to mark it as one?

Comment: for knowledge without clicking further links: hasKey() method comes from class org.hamcrest.Matchers

Comment: if it array and you want in place 1 example     .body("$", not(hasKey(array[1])));
it will not work

Comment: Wat if it's a nested json? I am guessing this "$" in the above expression would change to a descriptive path like "$.nameOfTheNode.AnotherNode" ?

Comment: I tried `body("$", not(hasKey("...")))` and it passes **also** for **existing** elements. I doubt it is correct. E.g. this passes: `.body("ultimate.answer", is("42")).body("$", not(hasKey("ultimate.answer")))` when the body contains `<ultimate><answer>42</answer></ultimate>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use equals(null) like this:

`.body("surname", equals(null))`

If the field does not exists it will be null

Comment: This also matches on a JSON field set to null.

Comment: You are right but if it receives null it's basically the same

Comment: It's not the same, because if a field is not set, then a JavaScript client will see it as `undefined` and not as `null`.

Comment: If you are trying to extract data from XML, and check is it empty, that approach will not work. The right one is:  body("$", not(hasKey("user.age")))

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov: I tried your `body("$", not(hasKey("...")))` and it passes **also** for **existing** elements. I doubt it is correct. E.g. this passes: `.body("ultimate.answer", is("42")).body("$", not(hasKey("ultimate.answer")))` when the body contains `<ultimate><answer>42</answer></ultimate>`

Answer (score 0):

Check whetever field is null. For example:

```
    Response resp = given().contentType("application/json").body(requestDto).when().post("/url");
    ResponseDto response = resp.then().statusCode(200).as(ResponseDto.class);
    Assertions.assertThat(response.getField()).isNotNull();
```

Answer (score -1):

Using: 
`import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;`

Your could then:
`assertThat(response.then().body(containsString("thingThatShouldntBeHere")),     is(false));`

Comment: please provide a rest assured solution

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem where my response included a field or not depending on the result set.  I found that you can use try/except to test the field (try) and if it isn't present then process the exception, which in my case, I just wanted to pass on it.  One could write code in the except to correct the errant field if that suits the use case.

```
try:
   something = response.json['field_name']
except:
   pass

# For op's use case:
try:
   surname = response.json['surname']
except:
   surname = None   # or whatever you'd like to do with a missing surname.
```

Comment: You should learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your posts. Also, I think it would improve your answer if you added some explanation of what the code does. Remember, answers are for everybody and not just for the OP.